# Codeigniter database access - ORMs performance

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, orm

I am re-factoring a codeigniter project that uses database extensively (right now that layer uses PDO and generated queries but it became unreadable so needs re-factoring), and trying to figure out what's the best way to go. I am interested in ease of development, but more importantly - performance, but I couldn't find out useful comparisons of performance:
CI's Active record, NotORM and ORMs (currently I am looking at GAS and Datamapper, but open to other suggestions) that can be integrated with CI .

I started looking at DataMapper, but then found a post claiming it is twice as slow as the CI Active Record, and that seems to me like a deal-breaker - I am ok with a bit of overhead for extra flexibility, code reuse and readability, but would rather with a really fast bad code than find out I significantly slowed my pages loading time for that.

I am looking for something like http://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/ , but for ORMs and other DB access layers and not PHP frameworks.

Comment: CI's "Active Record" is not an ORM and will be renamed to "Query Builder" in CI3.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there's no good answer here.

If you need extremely good performance, then use PDO. You write plain SQL queries, so you have 100% control.

If you want to introduce some tool to ease the way you write SQL, maybe you can have a look at any SQL-fluent-api library, that can abstract you "a bit":

```
select('X')->from('Y')->where('Z')->limit(10);
```

A bit clearer, maybe :). It'll probably also generate compatible-queries with many RDBMS (MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL...).

None of the above alternatives is an ORM. If you need it, of course there's a penalty on performance (and we can say it's always "big"). Good and modern ORMs usually allow you also to cache results, or even the generated SQL to avoid part of the overhead.

Anyway, the performance is degraded, of course. For each query, the ORM has to transform the resultset to your objects (and all the relations), which is (on the other hand) very cool :D. And you lose control over what the ORM is doing internally (sometimes, and if you don't know the ORM).

There's no good answer here, it depends on your use-case.

If you decide to use an ORM, have a look at Doctrine2. You can have a look at how to integrate it with CodeIgniter here: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/integrating-with-codeigniter.html